# Get edges of a given object

Tags: graphql

If I have a list of  `Post { id, title, createdAt, content }`, how would I go about getting the previous one and the next one in single query?

I tried

  `allPosts(
    first: 1,
    after: "cje4d8odwwqvz0155c4zs2n7i"
    last: 1,
    before: "cje4d8odwwqvz0155c4zs2n7i"
  ) {
    id
    title
  }`

But it is not allowed to combine both after and before according to the docs. I'm trying to get pointers for navigation arrows that allow a user to move to the previous or next post.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that GraphQL [aliases](https://github.com/mugli/learning-graphql/blob/master/3.%20Querying%20with%20Field%20Aliases%20and%20Fragments.md#field-aliases) allow running different queries inside of the same query.

Using the GraphCMS generated API I implemented the query that returns a full post and partial data from it's neighbors in this way using Apollo-Client.

```
export const GET_POST_AND_EDGES_QUERY = gql`
query GetPostQuery($strId: String!, $id: ID!) {
    Previous: allPosts (last: 1, before: $strId){
        ...PostFragment 
    }
    Post(id: $id) {
        author {
            firstName
            lastName
            thumbnail {
                url
            }
        }
        title
        createdAt
        tags
        content    

    }
    Next: allPosts(first: 1, after: $strId) {
        ...PostFragment 
    }
}

fragment PostFragment on Post {
    title
    slug
    id
}
`;
```

The reason I pass the same ID as a type `String` and type `ID` is that the generated API expects a String type in the use of `before` and `after` whilst the Post() query expects an `ID` type. If you have control over the schema, I suppose this could be changed so that the function signatures accept the same types.

I am not exactly sure if `before` and `after` accept other string types other than something resembling an `ID`.